# change drush module location

Tags: drush

I am looking how I can change the location that drush deals with when updating modules.
I want to set it to `/sites/all/modules/contrib`.

I have suceeded in changing the download (drush dl) location with  `$command_specific['dl'] = array('destination' => 'sites/all/modules/contrib');` in `drushrc.php`

How can I set this for updates. I guess something needs to be rebuilt?

I have seen something about using `drush-remake` with `--contrib-destination` set, but then im told i need to specify an "installation profile", is this really the proper way to set this?

Update: When I run `pm-list` in `sites/` it sees the modules but says they are not installed.

Comment: did you review http://drush.ws or the readme.txt?

Comment: yes, did i miss something?

Comment: Oh i just throwing it out there as advice.

Comment: usually the updates go where the modules are, I am afraid i dont get the point. make and remake are a different story. if you have several sites running, try to cd to one of them, you should probably see the installed modules properly ?

Comment: Ok, maybe it nothing to do with make/remake. Im trying to run the update from the main sites dir, not on each and every one.

Comment: While infact running from an individual site will find all the modules, i am a bit worried about doing it that way since they are infact shared modules.